# Aren't these Manusmṛti verses pertaining to marriage contradictory?

Tags: marriage, manu-smriti, varna

[Manusmṛti 3.23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199796.html) describes the form of marriages that are permitted for each Varṇa:

> षडानुपूर्व्या विप्रस्य क्षत्रस्य चतुरोऽवरान् ।
> विश्।शूद्रयोस्तु तानेव विद्याद् धर्म्यानराक्षसान् ॥ २३ ॥
>
> ṣaḍānupūrvyā viprasya kṣatrasya caturo'varān |
> viś|śūdrayostu tāneva vidyād dharmyānarākṣasān || 23 ||
>
> One should know the first six (Brāhma, Daiva, Ārsa, Prājāpatya, Āsura and Gāndharva) in the order stated as lawful for the Brāhmaṇa, **the last four (Āsura, Gāndharva, Rākṣasa and Paiśāca) for the Kṣatriya and those same, excepting the “Rākṣasa" (Āsura, Gāndharva and Paiśāca), for the Vaiśya and the Śūdra**.

[Manusmṛti 3.24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199797.html), then goes on, to further recommend which forms of marriages are best for each Varṇa:

> चतुरो ब्राह्मणस्याद्यान् प्रशस्तान् कवयो विदुः ।
> राक्षसं क्षत्रियस्यैकमासुरं वैश्यशूद्रयोः ॥ २४ ॥
>
> caturo brāhmaṇasyādyān praśastān kavayo viduḥ |
> rākṣasaṃ kṣatriyasyaikamāsuraṃ vaiśyaśūdrayoḥ ||
>
> The wise ones have regarded the first four as commended for the Brāhmaṇa, the Rākṣasa alone for the Kṣatriya and the **Āsura for the Vaiśya and the Śūdra**.

However, the very next verse ([Manusmṛti 3.25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199799.html)) goes on to forbid Paiśāca and Āsura marriages:

> पञ्चानां तु त्रयो धर्म्या द्वावधर्म्यौ स्मृताविह ।
> पैशाचश्चासुरश्चैव न कर्तव्यौ कदा चन ॥ २५ ॥
>
> pañcānāṃ tu trayo dharmyā dvāvadharmyau smṛtāviha |
> paiśācaścāsuraścaiva na kartavyau kadā cana || 25 ||
>
> Of the five (Prājāpatya, Gāndharva, Āsura, Rākṣasa and Paiśāca), three (Prājāpatya, Gāndharva and Rākṣasa) have been declared to be lawful and **two unlawful, in this treatise; the Paiśāca and the Āsura forms should never be adopted.**’

Therefore, to basically summarise my questions:

(1) Since [Manusmṛti 3.23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199796.html) permits Paiśāca marriages for non-Brāhmaṇas, why does [Manusmṛti 3.25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199799.html) seem to generally forbid Paiśāca marriages entirely?

(2) Since [Manusmṛti 3.23](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199796.html) permits Āsura marriages for non-Brāhmaṇas and even commends Vaiśyas and Śūdras for performing it in [Manusmṛti 3.24](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199797.html), why does [Manusmṛti 3.25](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199799.html) seem to generally forbid Āsura marriages entirely?

Aren't these verses contradictory to each other?

Lastly, it has been again reiterated that Paiśāca marriages are sinful in [Manusmṛti 3.34](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199809.html).

Comment: Manu/Indra tend to speak deceptively, but technically true. Anyway, he is probably giving his law on top of the general law like a national annex to an international set of regulations. He could have made this clearer.

Comment: By the way this implies "the Imperishable One" is not Brahma